# How to join with relative paths only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, filesystems, webserver

For a simple web server script, I wrote the following function that resolves the url to the file system.

```
def resolve(url):
    url = url.lstrip('/')
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), url))
    return path
```

Here are some example outputs for the `__file__` variable being `C:\projects\resolve.py`.

```
/index.html    => C:\projects\index.html
/\index.html   => C:\index.html
/C:\index.html => C:\index.html
```

The first example is just fine. The url get resolved to a file inside the directory of the script. However, I didn't expect the second and third example. Since the appended path is interpreted as an absolute path, it completely ignores the directory in which the script file lies.

This is a security risk since all files on the file system can be accesses, not just those inside the sub directory of the script. Why does Python's `os.path.join` allow joining with absolute paths and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.path.join()` is not suitable for unsafe input, no. It is entirely deliberate that an absolute path ignores arguments before it; this allows for supporting both absolute and relative paths in a configuration file, say, without having to test the entered path. Just use `os.path.join(standard_location, config_path)` and it'll do the right thing for you.

Take a look at [Flask's `safe_join()`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/helpers.py#L563-L587) to handle untrusted filenames:

```
import posixpath
import os.path

_os_alt_seps = list(sep for sep in [os.path.sep, os.path.altsep]
                    if sep not in (None, '/'))

def safe_join(directory, filename):
    # docstring omitted for brevity
    filename = posixpath.normpath(filename)
    for sep in _os_alt_seps:
        if sep in filename:
            raise NotFound()
    if os.path.isabs(filename) or \
       filename == '..' or \
       filename.startswith('../'):
        raise NotFound()
    return os.path.join(directory, filename)
```

This uses the `posixpath` (the POSIX implementation for the platform-agnostic `os.path` module) to normalise the URL path first; this removes any embedded `../` or `./` path segments, making it a fully normalised relative or absolute path.

Then any alternative separators other than `/` are excluded; you are not allowed to use `/\index.html` for example. Last but not least, absolute filenames, or relative filenames are specifically prohibited as well.